# How to filter data using multiple attributes?

Tags: magento-1.9, collection

I would like to get data with pre_order = 1 and if pre_order_due_date is `gt` than and id `ls` than so in my code I did:

```
$preordered = Mage::getModel("catalog/product")->getCollection()
->addFieldToFilter(
array(
      array('attribute' => 'pre_order', 'eq' => '1',
      array('attribute' => 'pre_order_due_date',
      array( 'gt' => $from, 'lt' => $to)
     ))));
```

It works but as a result I'm getting too many products, date filter seems not to work properly.
What should I change to make it work as expected ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$preordered = Mage::getModel("catalog/product")->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('pre_order')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('pre_order_due_date')  
    ->addFieldToFilter('pre_order', array('eq' => 1))
    ->addFieldToFilter('pre_order_due_date', array('gt' => $from))
    ->addFieldToFilter('pre_order_due_date', array('lt' => $to));
```

**OR**

```
$preordered = Mage::getModel("catalog/product")->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('pre_order')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('pre_order_due_date')
    ->addFieldToFilter('pre_order', array('eq' => 1))
    ->addAttributeToFilter(
            array(
                array('attribute'=>'pre_order_due_date','gt'=> $from),
                array('attribute'=>'pre_order_due_date', 'lt'=> $to)
            )
        );
```

**OR**

```
$filter2 = array('from'=> $from ,'to'=> $to);

$preordered = Mage::getModel("catalog/product")->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('pre_order')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('pre_order_due_date')  
    ->addFieldToFilter('pre_order', array('eq' => 1))
    ->addFieldToFilter('pre_order_due_date',array($filter2));
```

**OR**

```
$filter1 = array('gt' => $from);
$filter2 = array('lt' => $to);
$preordered = Mage::getModel("catalog/product")->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('pre_order')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('pre_order_due_date')  
    ->addFieldToFilter('pre_order', array('eq' => 1))
    ->addFieldToFilter('pre_order_due_date',array($filter1, $filter2));
```

Comment: Thank you Abdul, but there is one problem it will not select only those where pre_order = 1 and range between dates, as a result I'm getting all of them where pre_order = 1 instead of just one where pre_order = 1 and is in range of dates for example only one is in range but it gives me everything greater than $from regardless if it is lt than $to.

Comment: A have one item in database which should match selection so as a result I should get only 1 but getting 63 ;)

Comment: let me check and reply you

Comment: pre_order = 1 and pre_order_due_date > 2017-06-15 and pre_order_due_date < NOW() something like that :) and then as a result I should get only 1 item

Comment: Pls check now updated ans.

Comment: Bautiful, thank you Sir, will check immediately :)